# validating SOAP-Request with a SOAPHandler

Tags: validation, xsd, wsdl, xml-namespaces, soaphandler

I'm trying to validate a SOAP-Request against the Schemas defined in the WSDL. I'm using a SOAPHandler with a SOAP-Handler-Chain. It works the only problem is that when I'm validating the request, I get this error message:

```
cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'v1:latitude'. One of '{"http://schemas.domain.com/wsdl/fuelprice/v1/model":latitude}' is expected.
```

The WSDL looks like this:

```
<wsdl:definitions xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"
      xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"
      mlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
      mlns:http="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/http/"
      xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
      xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"
      xmlns:mime="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/mime/"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xmlns:tns="http://schemas.domain.com/wsdl/fuelprice/v1"
      xmlns:model="http://schemas.domain.com/wsdl/fuelprice/v1/model"
      xmlns:exception="http://schemas.domain.com/wsdl/fuelprice/v1/exception"
      targetNamespace="http://schemas.domain.com/wsdl/fuelprice/v1">
<wsdl:types>
    <xsi:schema xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="http://schemas.domain.com/wsdl/fuelprice/v1" elementFormDefault="qualified">
        <xsi:import namespace="http://schemas.domain.com/wsdl/fuelprice/v1/model" schemaLocation="common.xsd"/>
        <xsi:import namespace="http://schemas.domain.com/wsdl/fuelprice/v1/exception" schemaLocation="exception.xsd"/>
        <xsi:import namespace="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" schemaLocation="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"/>
        <xsi:element name="GetAreaFuelStationsRequest">
            <xsi:complexType>
                <xsi:sequence>
                    <xsi:element name="area" type="model:Area"/>
                </xsi:sequence>
                <xsi:attribute name="provider" type="xsi:string" use="optional"/>
                <xsi:attribute name="prices" type="xsi:boolean" use="required"/>
            </xsi:complexType>
        </xsi:element>
```

The XSD:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsi:schema xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:model="http://schemas.domain.com/wsdl/fuelprice/v1/model" targetNamespace="http://schemas.domain.com/wsdl/fuelprice/v1/model" elementFormDefault="qualified">
<xsi:complexType name="FuelStation">
    <xsi:complexType name="Area">
        <xsi:sequence>
            <xsi:element name="center" type="model:GeoLocation"/>
            <xsi:element name="radius" type="xsi:float"/>
        </xsi:sequence>
    </xsi:complexType>
    <xsi:complexType name="GeoLocation">
        <xsi:sequence>
            <xsi:element name="latitude" type="xsi:double"/>
            <xsi:element name="longitude" type="xsi:double"/>
        </xsi:sequence>
        <xsi:attribute name="ellipsoid" type="xsi:string" use="required"/>
    </xsi:complexType>
```

The source code fragment:

```
    try {
        context.getMessage().getSOAPPart().getEnvelope();
        schemas = getSchemas(new URL(wsdlURI.toString().concat(wsdl)));
        schema = factory.newSchema(schemas);
        validator = schema.newValidator();
        validator.validate(new DOMSource(xml));
    }
```

A request:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:v1="http://schemas.domain.com/wsdl/fuelprice/v1" xmlns:mod="http://schemas.domain.com/wsdl/fuelprice/v1/model">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <v1:GetAreaFuelStationsRequest provider="ep1" prices="true">
         <v1:area>
            <mod:center ellipsoid="false">
                 <v1:latitude>49.8385</v1:latitude>
                 <v1:longitude>8.5014</v1:longitude>
            </mod:center>
            <mod:radius>10</mod:radius>
         </v1:area>
      </v1:GetAreaFuelStationsRequest>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Can anybody see what is wrong here? I have set

```
elementFormDefault="qualified"
```

but it did not work.

Comment: Does your SOAP request not declare the `v1` namespace prefix to be `"http://schemas.domain.com/wsdl/fuelprice/v1/model"` ?

Comment: I added a request to the Question description.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I did to get it working:

1. I imported into the wsdl the soap/envelope schema
2. I got the request body element and created a document from it as the document root
3. I added to the body-element the soap/envelope namespace

Answer (score 2):

**The error message has a key clue:**

> cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with
>   element 'v1:latitude'. One of
>   '{"http://schemas.domain.com/wsdl/fuelprice/v1/model":latitude}' is
>   expected.

Notice that the `targetNamespace` of the XSD,

```
targetNamespace="http://schemas.domain.com/wsdl/fuelprice/v1/model"
```

disagrees with the declaration of the namespace prefix,

```
xmlns:v1="http://schemas.domain.com/wsdl/fuelprice/v1"
```

used by `latitude` in the request:

```
 <v1:latitude>49.8385</v1:latitude>
```

**Make them match to eliminate your error.**

Comment: I changed to make it match but I get now this error: "wsdl2java failed: org.apache.ws.commons.schema.XmlSchemaException: An imported schema was announced to have the namespace http://schemas.domain.com/wsdl/fuelprice/v1/model, but has the namespace http://schemas.domain.com/wsdl/fuelprice/v1"

Comment: Did you forget to update the corresponding `xs:import/@namespace`?

Comment: Hi, I also changed in wsdl from <xsi:import namespace="http://schemas.domain.com/wsdl/fuelprice/v1/model" schemaLocation="fuelprice_common.xsd"/> to <xsi:import namespace="http://schemas.domain.com/wsdl/fuelprice/v1" schemaLocation="fuelprice_common.xsd"/>

Comment: And in XSD from <xsi:schema xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:model="http://schemas.domain.com/wsdl/fuelprice/v1/model" targetNamespace="http://schemas.domain.com/wsdl/fuelprice/v1/model" elementFormDefault="qualified">
to <xsi:schema xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:v1="http://schemas.domain.com/wsdl/fuelprice/v1" targetNamespace="http://schemas.domain.com/wsdl/fuelprice/v1" elementFormDefault="qualified">

Comment: Would you like to have a look to the entire files? I would appreciate your help.

Comment: All files?  No, please always prune to a [**Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example (MCVE)**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that exhibits the problem.  It's getting hard to follow here what you've changed and what the current error is.  When fixing one error leads to the next in a series of errors, it would be clearer to ask a new question for the new error if its resolution is not obvious to you.  Thanks.